# How to compare an UPC and its Quantity to scanned UPCs and quantities

Tags: excel

I am attempting to compare an internal carton manifest against the physical contents of the carton.  I want to take the below information and compare them to see if they match.  If they match I should get a result of Correct and if they do not, I should get an Error.  Any assistance is appreciated.

EXAMPLE:
Carton UPC and Quantity
155341268495     3

Scanned UPC and Quantity
155341268495      2

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Simple VLookup should work for you. Assuming your data starts from A1 & B1 cell and scanned data starts from D1 & E1 cell. Put below formula to F1 cell.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(D1,A1:B5,2,0)=E1,"Correct","Not Correct")
```